# writeToFile working on iOS 7 not on iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I have been having an issue and I can't find anything about it.

I got some code to write files in the Documents folder with iOS. Checked the Apple documentation seems it's where I want to put the file for it to be available the next launch.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
- (void) writeToTextFile:(NSString *)logMessage inFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    //get the documents directory:
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.txt", documentsDirectory, fileName];

    NSLog(@"TEST path: %@", filePath);
    //save logMessage to the documents directory
    [logMessage writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
}
```

Now I'm using unit tests on this methods. It was working fine on the iOS 7.0.3 simulator, but when I switched to iOS 6.0 it doesn't work anymore.

In fact I found out that there was no Documents folder in "Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/" but there's one in the 7.0.3 folder.

I can't really find any differences on how writing to a file should be handled between 6 and 7. Should I test if the folder exists then create it if it's not there?

Comment: Your `filePath` is not valid. To create file path use `stringByAppendingPathComponent` method. like    `NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];`

Comment: Before asking here, you should probably add an error variable and read it in iOS 6, then tell us what it says. Assuming that it doesn't just tell you directly what's going wrong.

Comment: It's telling me directory not found

Comment: Tested  `NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];` it gives me the exact same path (minus .txt) and is getting me the same error. But it sure is cleaner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
NSString *string = @"Text to save";
NSString *filePath = @"filerecord.txt";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];

[string writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

UPDATE

Create Documents directory if not exists

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentsDirectory]) {

    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}

NSString *string = @"Text to save";
NSString *filePath = @"filerecord.txt";

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];

[string writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: This gives me the same "no such file or directory error" on iOS 6

Comment: try checking your error   
`NSError * error = nil;
BOOL success = [string writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
NSLog(@"Is success = %d, error = %@", success, error);`

Comment: 2014-02-26 09:27:50.773 xctest[93261:303] Is success = 0, error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x8a20080 {NSUnderlyingError=0x8a22110 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSFilePath=/Users/SeikoTheWiz/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Documents/filerecord.txt, NSUserStringVariant=Folder}

Comment: I think you have problems with your Simulator, try reset content in your simulator and try again

Comment: no changes :(
Tried deleting the while 6.0 folder to get it recreated as well, but still no Documents folder.

Comment: If you check your folders in your Simulators folders, 5.0, 6.1, 7.0 ... you will see you only have Documents Folder in the last. I guess xCode create this folder only in the last SDK, so you can create this folder Documents if not exist like I show you in my update

Comment: Simply creating the folder worked. I'm kind of surprised though that I can't find anywhere people saying that sometimes the folder just doesn't exists and should be created by hand.

Many thanks!